# Android - How to add latest sms to the conversation list while the activity is running?

Tags: android, sms, chat, contentobserver

I am working on a SMS chat app. I am wondering how to add the latest SMS(sent or receive) at the bottom of the listview when the activity is opened just like stock SMS app or any other messenger.

I tried using ContentObserver. As soon as there is some changes in SMS database, i tried reloading the ListView with the new Dataset but it is not working. Everytime to see a new SMS(sent of receive) i have to restart the app so the list could be reloaded. I want these new message to be displayed in chat window as soon as i sent or receive them just like the way we chat over gtalk, msn or any SMS app.

Here is my code:-

```
public class ThreadData extends ListActivity
{
private static final Uri SMS_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms");
HashMap<Long, BodyType> bodies = new HashMap<Long, BodyType>();
private String name, number;
private ListView listView;
private Activity activity;
ThreadDataAdapter adapter;
Handler handler;
ArrayList<BodyType> items;
private Context context;
private static final String PHONE_NUMBER_SEPARATORS = " ()-./";
static HashMap<String, ContactInfo.ContactDetail> info = new HashMap<String, ContactInfo.ContactDetail>();

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.chats);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    activity = this;
    context = this;
    listView = getListView();
    if(extras != null)
    {
        number = extras.getString("address");
        ContactInfo.ContactDetail nameInfo = getContactsDetailWithNumber(number);
        if(nameInfo != null)
        {
            name = nameInfo.name;
        }
        else
        {
            name = number;
        }
    }
    TextView person = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chat_person);
    person.setText(name);
    ImageButton callPerson = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.call_person);
    callPerson.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            popUpDialerAlert();
        }
    });

    buildMessageList();
    items = sortBodies(bodies);
    adapter = new ThreadDataAdapter(this, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setStackFromBottom(true);

    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(SMS_URI, true, new MyContentObserver(handler));
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, RBSMSService.class);
    //startService(intent);
}

public void loadListView()
{
    items.clear();
    items = sortBodies(bodies);
    adapter = new ThreadDataAdapter(this, items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setStackFromBottom(true);
}

public void buildMessageList()
{
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(SMS_URI, null, null, null, "date ASC");
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        BodyType bodyInfo = new BodyType();
        String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
        bodyInfo.body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
        Long date = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
        bodyInfo.date = date;
        String type =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"));
        if(type.equals("1"))
        {
            bodyInfo.type = "received";
        }
        else if(type.equals("2"))
        {
            bodyInfo.type = "sent";
        }
        else if(type.equals("3"))
        {
            bodyInfo.type = "draft";
        }

        String number = filterPhoneNumber(address);
        ContactInfo.ContactDetail nameInfo = getContactsDetailWithNumber(number);
        String personName = number;
        if(nameInfo != null)
        {
            personName = nameInfo.name;
        }
        else
        {
            personName = number;
        }
        if(personName.equals(name))
       {
           bodies.put(date, bodyInfo);
       }

    }
}

public void popUpDialerAlert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder dialerAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialerAlert.setTitle("Confirm");
    dialerAlert.setMessage("Call" + " " + name + "?");
    dialerAlert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
            Intent intent = new Intent((Intent.ACTION_CALL));
            intent.setData(uri);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    dialerAlert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    dialerAlert.show();
}

public ArrayList<BodyType> sortBodies(HashMap<Long, BodyType> bodies)
{
    ArrayList<Long> dates = new ArrayList<Long>(bodies.keySet());
    Collections.sort(dates);
    ArrayList<BodyType> items = new ArrayList<BodyType>();
    for(Long date : dates)
    {
        for(Long key : bodies.keySet())
        {
            if(date.equals(key))
            {

                items.add(bodies.get(key));
            }
        }
    }
    return items;
}

public void printBodies(ArrayList<BodyType> items)
{
    for(BodyType bodyType : items)
    {
        log(bodyType.date.toString());
        log(bodyType.body);
        log(bodyType.type);
    }
}

static class BodyType
{
    public String type;
    public String body;
    public Long date;

}


public static ContactInfo.ContactDetail getContactsDetailWithNumber(String number)
{
    if(info.containsKey(number))
    {
        return info.get(number);
    }
    return null;
}

public static String filterPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber)
{
    if (phoneNumber == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    int length = phoneNumber.length();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        char character = phoneNumber.charAt(i);

        if (PHONE_NUMBER_SEPARATORS.indexOf(character) == -1)
        {
           builder.append(character);
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

public class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver
{

    public MyContentObserver(Handler handler)
    {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
    {
        bodies.clear();
        buildMessageList();
        items = sortBodies(bodies);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                loadListView();
            }
        });
        super.onChange(selfChange);
    }
}

public void log(String msg)
{
    Log.e("ThreadData", msg);
}
}
```

Please Help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to your list (items).

When the content provider calls OnChange, clear the very same list (don't create a new object, recycle your list) and add again your new mails. As this list is tied to your adapter, then it will update your listview when you call notifyDataChanged.

You *must* recycle the same list.

Regards
 Stéphane
PS : please note that you could have kept your old thread to ask the same question again.

Comment: LOL sorry for starting a new thread but i thought it is something different and if i'll put it in a new thread then it could help others in future. By the way thanks for helping me but notifyDataSetChanged() is still not working on custom adapter and coz of this i have to reload the list into an adapter every time. I have updated the code please take a look.

Comment: OK, I will put it more clear : don't do *new* ArrayList. Only once.

Answer (score 0):

So, to get the list to scroll to the bottom when you add new items, you should set it to be in "[transcriptMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3atranscriptMode)". However, the fact that you have to *restart* your app for new content to show tells me something else is wrong.

Edit: Stephane is right, don't call `buildMessageList();` again when you get the `onChange` notification just update the data in the adapter and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`